# Create a RESTful url for a php script

Tags: php, url

I have a php script on a webserver. Currently, the script is being accessed as `http://www.mydomain.com/scriptname.php` . 
Is there a way i can create a user friendly url for accessing this script, something like `http://www.mydomain.com/appname,` so when this url is called it invokes the php script ?

Please help.
Thank You

Comment: Your title is "creating a RESTful .." - There's nothing really RESTful about your question, so I'm assuming you don't really know what REST is and how it is used - if your an API programmer, or programmer of clients that consume a RESTful API, you should definitely read up on REST. Starting points are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want mod_rewrite if you're using Apache HTTPD: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If you're using a different web server, it may have something similar (lighttpd has a similar functionality builtin).

Once it's enabled, you can use something like this in your .htaccess file to rewrite appname to scriptname.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^appname$ scriptname.php
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to your apache/lighttpd configuration file a little hack that may work is putting the script in `http://www.mydomain.com/appname/index.php`; `http://www.mydomain.com/appname/` will then probably work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andreas. Actually this was what i was looking for as i have purchased an account with a web hosting provider, but dont have shell access. Thank You !

Comment: You don't need shell access to change .htaccess settings. But if this works for you, it is fine as well.

Comment: You could also rename your script to `appname.php`, and as long as there is no `appname` directory there as well, Apache will usually execute the .php file.

Answer (score -1):

Using the default settings of most PHP hosts, you can put the file "index.php" inside your folder http://www.mydomain.com/appname, then fill the index.php with next code:

```
<?php
header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/scriptname.php");
?>
```

That would do it.

Comment: That would do a redirect. Among other things, that would change the URL to http://www.mydomain.com/scriptname.php, which I assume the asker does not want.